# How to arrange forms fields vertically?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a login form by using the Forms class. Unfortunately, when I run the page I found the arrangement of the fields is horizontal. Can you help me to make it vertically, please?

In the bellow the forms.py code:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length = 50)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

And here is the views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Login
from .forms import LoginForm 
  
# Create your views here.
 
def login_function(request):
    try:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        data = Login(username = username, password = password)
        data.save()
    except:
        x = 'error'
    return render(request,'pages/login.html', {'loginform':LoginForm})
```

And here is login.html code:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{loginform}}            
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Way using `as_p`**

```html
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{loginform.as_p}}            
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Second Way using loop**
If you want to add any additional styles to your form, then

```html
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in loginform%}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} <br/>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Third-way using table**

```html
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
       {{ loginform.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it. It works properly as I wish.

Comment: `as_div()` and `as_ul()` methods are also available, see Django documentation for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#output-styles